# combination of hashmap with arraylist for making complex structure

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, hashmap

last 3 days i am spending time to get the following structure working but i wont be able to figure out that how to get the structure working

```
array
  1 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => '1'
          'name' => 'xyz'
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => '12'
          'name' => 'xyz1'
      2 => 
        array
          'id' => '54'
          'name' => 'xyz12'
  20 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => '1'
          'name' => 'xyz'
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => '12'
          'name' => 'xyz1'
      2 => 
        array
          'id' => '54'
          'name' => 'xyz12'
      3 => 
        array
          'id' => '566'
          'name' => 'xyz1234'
```

i tried following thing but i wont be able to move forward

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> data  = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>();
```

i have a resultset, in that i have information as follows

```
id               | name                      | element_id
______________________________________________________________
1                | xyz                       | 1
______________________________________________________________
1                | xyz                       | 3
______________________________________________________________
12               | xyz1                      | 1
______________________________________________________________
54               | xyz11                     | 1
______________________________________________________________
566              | xyz1234                   | 3
______________________________________________________________
12               | xyz1                      | 3
______________________________________________________________
54               | xyz11                     | 3
______________________________________________________________
```

My code is

```
while (resultSET.next()) 
{
    Map<String, Object> tag = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    tag.put("name", resultSET.getString(3));
    tag.put("id", resultSET.getInt(2));

    tags.put(resultSET.getInt(1), tag);
}
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here. You are not asking any question. What is not working?

Comment: Your input looks like a mapping int -> int -> string -> string, so you can use something like `Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Map<String,String>>>, but it will be cumbersome to use.

Comment: i updated the question, my code as well..! how to get the code working thats the problem

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with collections of collections (of collections...) things tend to quickly become confusing. Try encapsulating the different collections in (descriptively named) objects, and I suspect it will be easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>> result = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Integer>>>();
```

Where in the final map you will store the values

```
'id' => '1'
          'name' => 'xyz'
```

and for the second level map you should store

```
0 => 
        array
          'id' => '1'
          'name' => 'xyz'
```

And for the final outer map you should store

```
1 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => '1'
          'name' => 'xyz'
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => '12'
          'name' => 'xyz1'
      2 => 
        array
          'id' => '54'
          'name' => 'xyz12'
```

Hope this works for you

Enjoy !!!

Comment: i did it, the way i want..! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487450/combination-of-hashmap-with-arraylist-for-making-complex-structure/10493303#10493303)

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object> tag = new HashMap<String, Object>();
tag.put("name", resultSET.getString(3));
tag.put("id", resultSET.getInt(2));
```

One obvious simplification you can do is to make tag a class having attributes name and id. Is there some reason why you would not want to do that?

---

Regarding the problem with your current code:

```
tags.put(resultSET.getInt(1), tag);
```

You will need to create an array list containing tag and then put that in the tags.

Comment: yes, that is other way of doing it but as its j2ee application, then i have make that PUBLIC class with PUBLIC attribute, which i don not want

Answer (score 0):

It was not that much difficult...! got it finally...!!

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> tags  = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>();

while (routeRs1.next()) 
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> temp_tags    =   new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> tag     =   new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if(tags.get(routeRs1.getInt(1)) == null)
    {
        tag.put("name", routeRs1.getString(3));
        tag.put("id", routeRs1.getInt(2));

        temp_tags.add(tag);

    }
    else
    {
        temp_tags   =   (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) tags.get(routeRs1.getInt(1));

        tag.put("name", resultSET.getString(3));
        tag.put("id", resultSET.getInt(2));
        temp_tags.add(tag);
    }
    tags.put(resultSET.getInt(1), temp_tags);
}
```

simple concepts of software is break down the problem......! :D